# Не переведено сообщение "назначено удаление профиля"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, удаление-профиля

Секция о подтверждении удаления профиля (появляющаяся после нажатия на красную кнопку) не переведена на русский:

[image: скриншот]

> ## Profile deletion scheduled
>
> ---
>
> Your profile has been successfully scheduled for deletion. You can cancel this request by clicking the button below; otherwise, your profile will be automatically deleted within 24 hours.
>
> Due to your number of votes and/or your reputation, this deletion will require final approval from a developer after the 24 hours before it is completed. Once approved, your profile will be deleted immediately - you do not need to schedule your profile for deletion again.

---

Кроме того, на электронную почту прилетело письмо, куда тоже закрался абзац на английском:

> If you need anything else, please visit our **contact form<sup>ссылка</sup>** and select 'Other' for additional help.

Comment: Вы всё-таки не отказались от этой затеи )=

Comment: Вроде же раньше переведено сообщение было...

Comment: @PavelMayorov раньше другой текст был, как минимум для части текста  =/

Comment: Зайти, что выйти навсегда, но без бага нельзя? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Кстати, некоторые при удалении репу в конкурсы трансформируют. Я не призываю, просто так - идею вспомнил.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ всё равно одновременно вроде только 3 конкурса возможно создать.

Comment: @Suvitruf `0<3` как тут иногда любят писать.

Comment: Не, 22 килорепы даже порциями по 500 раздавать очень долго, а для этого ещё и очень интересные вопросы искать, стоящие этих 500 баллов за хороший ответ... Нет, я пас.

Comment: @D-side можно раздать на существующие ответы. Ну или просто не уходить :)

Comment: @PashaPash искать ещё и интересные ответы под интересными вопросами? Это ещё дольше :)

Comment: @D-side пройдите по top по любимым меткам, и раздайте "один из ответов заслуживает дополнительной награды".

Comment: @PashaPash от сортировки с топа лучше не становится, "мои любимые метки весьма специфичны, вы не поймёте" :)

Comment: @D-side та_самая_картинка.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/8523

Добавил перевод:

> Запланировано удаление профиля

Для [текста сообщения](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Your%20profile%20has%20been%20successfully%20scheduled%20for%20deletion) добавил перевод:

> Запрос на удаление вашего профиля добавлен в очередь. Вы можете отменить его, нажав кнопку ниже; в противном случае ваш профиль будет автоматически удалён в течение $DeleteAfterNumHours$ часов.

Для [этих строк](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Due%20to%20your%20number%20of%20votes%20and%2For%20your%20reputation) часть текста взял из старой строки `e1957f926fd034b445bf7b799507cab6`:

> Из-за вашей репутации и/или количества голосов удаление требует окончательного утверждения разработчиком через $DeleteAfterNumHours$ часов. После утверждения ваш профиль будет удалён незамедлительно - вам не нужно запрашивать удаление снова.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12618 и https://ru.traducir.win/string/2047

> Если у вас остались другие вопросы, пожалуйста, посетите нашу контактную форму и выберите *Другое* для получения дополнительной помощи.

Comment: "Запланирован запрос на удаление профиля" — в оригинале не упоминается запрос, запланировано само удаление. 

Comment: @D-side "Запланировано удаление профиля"?

Comment: Так точнее, да.

Comment: Ещё одна деталь нашлась, можете поправить? См. вопрос.

Comment: @D-side добавил перевод.